# Python - reassign priority list with the lowest possible values

Tags: python, python-3.x

The priorities range can be from 1 to 99.

Comment: What did you try, and how did it not work? Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
def reassignedPriorities(priorities):
    ordered_raw_priorities = sorted(set(priorities))
    priority_dict = {ordered_raw_priorities[i]: i + 1 for i in range(len(ordered_raw_priorities))}
    
    return [priority_dict[e] for e in priorities]
```

Using `enumerate` the code could be even simplified:

```
def reassignedPriorities(priorities):
    ordered_raw_priorities = sorted(set(priorities))
    priority_dict = {
        e: i for i, e in enumerate(ordered_raw_priorities, start=1)
    }
    
    return [priority_dict[e] for e in priorities]
```

Then if you call

```
reassignedPriorities([1,3,7,3])
```

the output will be

```
[1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Sorting a list before using `set` is useless ;)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco, updated! (good catch, it is totally useless)

Comment: Also, it's also useless to create a list before using `sorted`. I would rather use `sorted(set(priorities))`

Comment: @RiccardoBucco, I have learned something new... I didn't know that `sorted` was going to convert the set. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Answer has been Updated!

Comment: The only problem I have with this answer is that it rewards OP for a question that shows no effort to try and solve the problem themselves.